# How to setup multiple mount points and two separate playlist in the single icecast server?

Tags: icecast

Below is my sample icecast configuration. Can you suggest me how to create multiple mount points. I want to create a separate playlist for each mount point. Is that possible ?

```
IP=1.2.4.5
PORT=8000
SERVER=2
MOUNT=/radiostation2
PASSWORD=password
FORMAT=1
MP3PATH=m3u:/usr/local/etc/playlist2.m3u
LOOP=1
SHUFFLE=1
NAME=RadioStation 2: MP3
DESCRIPTION=Test Radio
GENRE=Varios
URL=http://localhost:8000/
LOG=2
LOGPATH=/var/log/icecast/playlist1.log
BITRATE=48000
SOURCE=source
```

Thanks,
Raja K

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are specifying server options and also a playlist.

You need an application to supply icecast with music, such as ices or mpd. This tutorial discusses setting up icecast and also setting up an application to play music (a source): https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-a-streaming-audio-server-with-icecast-2.3.3-on-centos-6.3-x86_64-linux